# Repopulate dropdownlist on click of first item

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net

I have two dropdowns, dependent upon each other selection. Now what I want is to reload both dropdown, when user clicks on first item, i.e, index 0.

onchange event is already associated with the dropdowns, so selectedindexchanged event is not being called.

What else can be done in this scenario?

Comment: Already tried Autopostback="true", but in vain.
And, wanted to clarify one thing, two event can be associated with one control?
Like in my case, OnChange event is associated with my dropdown, and now am trying to add selectedindex changed event. Is it possible?

Comment: show us the relevant code of aspx and codebehind

Answer (score 2):

'so selectedindexchanged event is not being called.'

In the properties for your combobox, set 'AutoPostBack' to true and this event will now be called.

Sorry; had to make an edit - I meant true not false.

Edit:

OnChange event is associated with my dropdown, and now am trying to add selectedindex changed event. Is it possible?

Yes, controls can have many events attached to it.

Code which works for selectedindex :

```
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        for (int i = 1; i < 10; i++)
        {
            DropDownList1.Items.Add(i.ToString());
        }

        DropDownList1.AutoPostBack = true;
    }

    protected void DropDownList1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }
```

Comment: Tried this also, but in vain.

Comment: Does the event work or not? If the event is called you can then do something like:
public void indexchanged() {
cboMyCombo = cboMyCombo.Index[1]
}

Comment: onchange event is working but selectedindex change event not working